# How to decrease apk size when using Neshan Maps Android SDK?

Tags: android, neshan, neshan-android-sdk, neshan-platform, neshan-map

I've recently switched my application map sdk from Google Maps to Neshan Maps SDK for Android. But the application size was increased about 24MB after implementing NeshanMaps SDK in my project.

Before using this new map sdk, the size of my application was about 6MB.

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/neshan/neshan-android-sdk" }
}
```

I guess I made a mistake and size should not be greater than 10MB.
Does any one have same problem? How can I reduce the size of the application.

PS. neshan maps sdk site is here: https://developers.neshan.org/android-sdk/guides/getting-started

Comment: do you use proguard minification?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko As I know developers should exclude Neshan Maps SDK file from their proguard minification: -keep class org.neshan.** {*;}

Comment: No, I did not use proguard at all @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently we've update our documentation in [Neshan Maps Platform](https://developers.neshan.org) developers site. As we mentioned in the new Android SDK Getting Started page, you can use this `split` config to reduce final application size:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

---

Also as Ahmad said you should exclude `org.neshan.*` classes from proguard minification by this rule in `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
 -keep class org.neshan.** {*;}
```

Comment: Which section in `build.gradle` file should I put this splits config?

Comment: @NishamS Just put `split` in the `android` section in your app build.gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

see this link and contact neshan support if you cant find the answer.

https://neshan.blog/neshan-maps-android-sdk-intro-hntmb8edjg5r?_ga=2.232603740.25620901.1580805934-5423412.1577344656

Comment: 1. Quote the answer if there is one in the linked page. 2. The Link sites to a page which is not in english language! 3. Don't post any answer if you can't quote or write it directy/yourself.